# How to check if an artifactory artifact exists?

Tags: rest, artifactory

I've got a path to the artifact but I do not want to download it, just check whether it exists. 
What would be the "cheapest/fastest" way to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I know already...

I can use the HEAD-http method.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use ['search'](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles) in [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli):

```
$ jfrog rt s libs-release-local/Bazinga --count
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 1 artifact.
1

$ jfrog rt s libs-release-local/Bazingaaaaa --count
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 0 artifacts.
0
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding an answer here in case other people are hunting for this like I was.

Buried in the docs, you can do a GET query to `http://{your_artifactory_url}/api/storage/{path/to/file}`. Make sure you allow redirects.

Note that this is different from the url you use to PUT files.